# How to display a message or redirect to a page based on the values that are selected from a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

this is a form in my asp.net mvc application.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ApproveReject", "Admin"))
{

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Admin_Approval)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Admin_Approval, new SelectList(Model.ApproveRejectValues, "Id", "value"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>


@Html.HiddenFor(a => a.pm_main_rep.Id);
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

As you can see it has a drop down list with some values, I want to display different messages or redirect to different pages based on the values that are selected by users.

For example, if user select yes from dropdown it should display a message like: are you sure you want to confirm?

And in case of no, it should display a text box to get users feedback that why they selected no.

At least if you guys hint me with the basics, i will try to find my way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to do that in Javascript. Listen to the save button click/change event of the SELECT, read the selected option and show appropriate message as needed,

Comment: As an extension of Shyju's comment, I recommend you look into a JS library named ""Bootbox". I've used it to simply these kinds of Yes/No/Enter Text inputs you're going to need.It can make it much easier to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Javascript. For example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<select name="sweets" >
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>
 
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
   alert( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```